# Resize partition - Failed to find physical volume

Tags: virtualbox, lvm, resize

I followed [tutorial](https://web.archive.org/web/20201026070250/https://technology.amis.nl/2017/01/30/ubuntu-vm-virtualbox-increase-size-disk-make-smaller-exports-distribution/) to resize a hard disk in virtual machine. In the last step when I shoot the command `sudo pvresize /dev/sda1` I am getting this error: `Failed to find physical volume "/dev/sda1"`. From my research it looks like that I should point to a different path, but I'm not sure what should it be.

Comment: Can you please link the guide with the steps you used attempting to resize the hard disk?

Comment: @Robby1212 Of course. I just added it to the question.

Comment: Are you trying to make the drive larger or smaller?

Comment: Larger. From 16GB to 30GB

Comment: From Step 5 can you send a screenshot of what you see in GParted?

Comment: Sure, you can see it here: https://i.imgur.com/UsbWlqf.png

Comment: I could make it work. After step 5 I realized that a 'v' icon was activated, I clicked on it, confirmed the operation and after reboot the OS the disk had been resized. This action on the 'v' icon is not on the tutorial. I don't know if the tutorial is lacking some step or if my machine is the one missing something, since the command line still doesn't work. Anyway, thank you for your time and if you believe that there is something wrong with my machine I would apprecite any tip. Thank you again.

Comment: Looks good to me! VMs are a great way to test without borking your system.

Answer (score 0):

I happen to just not have any physical volumes. You can check this by calling `pvdisplay`. I've ommited this step and that haven't cause any problem. I just had to resize the filesystem (partition) after reboot.

Comment: It probably cannot find a volume because of the VM. Its perspective is from atop a hypervisor instead, but that hypervisor layer is running atop an OS layer, which is inside a volume. Beyond that, it might as well be magic to me. Pretty sure VM doesn't know all this, because it doesn't realize that its a VM. This is part of the allure with VMs.

Comment: The errors can be avoided with a bit of configuration. I do not have the specifics on hand; I am just making sure that you know where to start if you decide to set it up. I suggest you google something like "configure VM to see localhost" and go from there. Also, keep in mind that he Linux OS partition will not always be `dev/sda1`. For example, mine is on `dev/sda4`.

Comment: @user1164434 "I am just making sure that you know where to start if you decide to set it up" - set what up? in my case pvresize just wasn't needed.